# XmlSerializer and types

Tags: c#, xml, types, xml-serialization

I have a class that handles XMLs serialization.

```
public class DB
{
    public List<Connection> lstConnections { get; set; }
    static string sRootAttribute = "Connections";

public static DB LoadFromFile(string path)
{
    FileStream fs = null;
    DB db = null;

    try
    {
        fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DB), new XmlRootAttribute(sRootAttribute));
        db = (DB)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    if (fs != null)
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

    return db;
}

public static void SaveToFile(string path, object objData)
{
    var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objData.GetType(), new XmlRootAttribute(sRootAttribute));

    try
    {
        serializer.Serialize(fs, objData);
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    fs.Close();
}
```

}

The `LoadFromFile` method is somewhat generic, because it doesn't consider the serialized data type.
However, `SaveToFile` does `GetType` on the object that is being serialized.
Therefore, when I'm trying to deserialize the file with `LoadFromFile` I'm having problems.  I'm not getting any exceptions, but the `lstConnections` is empty.

Comment: The code generated by `Xsd2Code` has a bunch of [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx). I guess serializer relies on  some attribute like `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute` to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ownership over the Connection class, then:

1. Decorate the Connection class with *[System.SerializableAttribute()]* and  *[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]*.
2. Decorate the connections list property with *[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("connection", IsNullable=false)]*. Though I guess you will be safer with an array and a property that's not auto implemented.
3. Decorate the DB class with: *[System.SerializableAttribute()]*,   *[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]* and   *[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]*
4. All public properties of Connection that return primitive types will get automatically serialized. Unless you specifically decorate them with *[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]*, then they'll be serialized as attributes.
5. You must also handle serialization for non primitive return type properties of Connection similarly. Decorate properties that return collections with *XmlArrayItemAttribute* and mark each custom subtype as serializable.